# I had an account on USCIS but lost my mobile number

Tags: immigration, visa

I have an account on USCIS online site https://www.uscis.gov/, but I don't have anymore the phone number I used to have to receive the codes to login. Also, I'm not in the USA anymore, what makes more complicated to look for support/help. I tried to create a ticket or service request for support but it's asking me for an A-##### recceipt number that I don't have.

My best guess would it be to create a new account, is that okay? I used to use it for following up appointments but the same I can do with a new account. Is that correct?

Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question about the law.

Comment: “it's asking me for an A-##### recceipt number that I don't have.” So don’t put one in.